# Yii Framework 1.1 CdbCriteria with multiple JOIN in GridView

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I'm starting in the world Yii framework in version 1.1 and it's impossible for me to visualize the records brought from a pure query. It's been days since I can't solve it, it's probably something simple but with my poor knowledge I haven't been able to solve it yet. I show you my code to see if you can help me.

The relationships of the `TblRecibo` model, which is where I want to make the query are:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'tblEstadoreciboHasTblRecibos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TblEstadoreciboHasTblRecibo', 'idRecibo'),
        'tblItemrecibowebs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TblItemreciboweb', 'idRecibo'),
        'idCalendario0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblCalendario', 'idCalendario'),
        'idDomicilioApertura0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblDomicilio', 'idDomicilioApertura'),
        'idDomicilio0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblDomicilio', 'idDomicilio'),
        'idPaquete0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblPaquete', 'idPaquete'),
    );
}
```

My model:

```
public function search()
{      
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->alias = 'r';
    $criteria->select = 'r.idRecibo,d.matricula,d.federado,e.nombre,d.calle,r.cantidad,cal.periodo,est.ult_modif,os.nombre ';
    $criteria->join ='LEFT JOIN tbl_calendario as cal on r.idcalendario=cal.idcalendario '
            .'LEFT JOIN tbl_estadorecibo_has_tbl_recibo as est on r.idrecibo=est.idrecibo '
            .'LEFT JOIN tbl_domicilio as d ON r.iddomicilioapertura=d.idDomicilio '
            .'LEFT JOIN tbl_entidad as e ON d.idEntidad=e.idEntidad '
            .'LEFT JOIN tbl_itemreciboweb as rweb on r.idrecibo=rweb.idrecibo '
            .'LEFT JOIN tbl_ooss as os on rweb.idooss=os.idooss';
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
        ),
    ));
}
```

My controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new TblRecibo('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if (isset($_GET['TblRecibo']))
        $model->attributes = $_GET['TblRecibo'];
    $this->render('admin', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

My view:

```
<?php
 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
   'type'=>'bordered striped',
    'id' => 'tbl-recibo-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'htmlOptions'   =>array('style' => 'font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal'),
    'columns' => array(
        'idrecibo',
        'dom.matricula',
        'dom.federado',
        'ent.nombre',
        'dom.calle',
        'rec.cantidad',
        'cal.periodo',
        'est.ult_modif',
        'os.nombre',
    ),
));
?>
```

When executing I have no error just that the `GridView` does not show the results of the queries. I know it should not be anything complicated because, debugging the values ​​are the issue is that I do not understand how to pass them to the Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With select like `r.idRecibo,d.matricula,d.federado, ...` result will be returned with keys like `idRecibo`, `matricula`, `federado` etc. Tho handle such query you need to add all fields from joined tables to your model:

```
TblRecibo extends CActiveRecord {

    public $matricula;
    public $federado;
    // ...
}
```

And then in grid view access them by:

```
'columns' => array(
    'idRecibo',
    'matricula',
    'federado',
    // ...
),
```

---

But for such custom queries it may be easier to use [`CSqlDataProvider`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider) instead of `CActiveDataProvider` - you will not need to add properties to model only for this search - result will be returned as array:

```
public function search() {      
    $from = 'FROM tbl_recibo as r '
            . 'LEFT JOIN tbl_calendario as cal on r.idcalendario=cal.idcalendario '
            . 'LEFT JOIN tbl_estadorecibo_has_tbl_recibo as est on r.idrecibo=est.idrecibo '
            . 'LEFT JOIN tbl_domicilio as d ON r.iddomicilioapertura=d.idDomicilio '
            . 'LEFT JOIN tbl_entidad as e ON d.idEntidad=e.idEntidad '
            . 'LEFT JOIN tbl_itemreciboweb as rweb on r.idrecibo=rweb.idrecibo '
            . 'LEFT JOIN tbl_ooss as os on rweb.idooss=os.idooss';
    $count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) ' . $from)->queryScalar();
    $sql = 'SELECT r.idRecibo,d.matricula,d.federado,e.nombre,d.calle,r.cantidad,cal.periodo,est.ult_modif,os.nombre ' . $from; 

    return new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
        'totalItemCount' => $count,
        'pagination' => array(
             'pageSize' => Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
        ),
    ));
}
```